# 404 Page not found on ddev TYPO3 installation

Tags: typo3, ddev

I have herited a project that is running good on the client side.

The website is a TYPO3 Based on ddev composer setup.

When i started the containers and go to the website url (backend or frontend) it shows :
[image]

It seems that something is maybe missing but i'm not sure what this could be, can you please help ? Thank you!

TYPO3 v10
DDEV recently updated

Comment: The most common problems of this type are these:
1. You have not run `mkcert -install` so are not using https to access the site. That's probably why it says "not secure". Do that and do a `ddev poweroff`
2. Check your docroot in .ddev/config.yaml. Does it correspond to the directory where your index.php is?

This type of question really requires more interactivity than works on SO, so come on over to Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k

Comment: Oh, and of course... did you do a `ddev composer install` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i have tried all this, but the problem still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used those command to resolve this issue:

```
ddev poweroff
ddev composer install
```

then i have stopped a traefik container that was running for a different project.

My website is now running.